# how can i improve performance to client side application with svg elements as real time application?

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, svg, real-time

As I am planning to create sample real time web application using SVG Elements with Angular or Javascript Code.
I would like to know how can i improve performance of client side with  SVG elements as real time application with SignalR broadcasting?

I want to know how can i code to perform real time operation as move , resize and rotation to perform quick DOM operation & increase speed in rendering in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose Angular then follow below

- Implement Socket on a global level and handle ON events in the hierarchy structure.
- Implement Lazy Loading Modules.
- OnPush Change Detection strategy.
- Avoid Function Calls in Views try to make pipes for it.
- Unsubscribe observables when you subscribe.
- Use of Track By Function for virtual DOM.

this might be helpful for better performance